# Endung "für den Autopilot" oder "den Autopiloten"

Tags: grammar, standard-german

Ich habe folgende Frage:
Ich möchte demnächst meine Bachelorthesis anmelden und habe vom Professor auch eine bereits formulierte Aufgabenstellung bekommen. Das Thema lautet (Ausschnitt):

> Entwicklung einer Einstellregel für den generischen Autopilot[en] [...]

Die Frage ist nun, ob ich *Autopilot* mit der Endung *-en* (meine Vermutung) oder eben ohne (Formulierung vom Prof) Recht habe. Es ist eigentlich banal, aber es wäre echt peinlich, wenn bereits das Thema einen Grammatikfehler hätte.

Comment: Mit "-en"... in 50 oder 100 Jahren aber wahrscheinlich schon ohne. Beim Akkusativ fällt die Endung mehr oder mehr gerne schon mal weg.

Comment: [http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Autopilot](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Autopilot)

Comment: Danke, habe ich also ein richtiges Gefühl gehabt. Duden hätte ich natürlich auch selber drauf kommen können...

Comment: Auf Deutsch ist es mE richtigerweise eine Bachelorarbeit, keine Bachelorthese (oder gar Denglisch -thesis) </mecker>

Comment: Da der Autopilot ja eben kein  (echter) Pilot ist, schmeckt mir die Dudenversion nicht. (Mal wieder..)

Comment: @Em1 Eher 5 bis 10, dann natürlich auch _des Autopilots_.

Comment: @TaW, dekliniert sich nicht auch "falscher Hase" wie "Hase"?

Comment: Nicht wirklich, denke ich mal..  Es ist ja ein feststehender Begriff; wie sieht es da mit z.B. Plural aus? Und auch beim Akkusativ: 'Ich esse gerne junge Hasen' -?> 'Ich esse gerne falsche Hasen' ? Wohl eher nicht, oder?

Comment: Aber @TaW: Wie ist es mit dem Akk.Sg.: "Ich esse gerne falschen Hase"? *schauder*

Comment: "Ich esse gerne 'falscher Hase'." würde ich sagen, aber "Ich esse gerne 'falschen Hasen'."  klingt auch ok, eventuell etwas legerer..

Answer (score 5):

> Der Begriff „Autopilot“ ist ein Kompositum der zwei Begriffe „Automat“ und „Pilot“. [<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autopilot#Definition)

Da gelten die Beugungsrsregel für das letzte Nomen, *Pilot*. Es ist egal, dass das nicht mehr ein echter Pilot ist. Auch abstrakte, leblose Objekte wie *Graph* beugt man mittels der N-Deklination – und auch in Akkusativ.

---

Das ist die Theorie. Natürlich wäre aber interessanter zu wissen, wie sich das entwickelt und ob die *N*-Deklination für solche Worte nicht mehr gelten soll. Ein [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=den%20Autopilot%2Cden%20Autopiloten&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cden%20Autopiloten%3B%2Cc0) deutet aber darauf hin, dass die *N*-Deklination des Nomens *Autopilot* in Akkusativ in den gescannten Büchern nicht nur überwiegt, sondern auch die einzige ist:

[image]

Comment: +1 schon gegeben. Nochmal +1 für das ngram geben wollend.

Comment: Hm, egal was Wikipedia meint, ist es doch eher so gelaufen: Autopilot kommt aus dem Englischen und dort von automatic + pilot. - Was aber nichts Zwingendes über die Frage der Deklination sagt.. - Die widerstrebenden Gefühle in der Frage, wenigstens bei mir, kommen wohl daher, dass ein Autopilot eben nicht nur kein Pilot ist sondern überhaupt auch kein Ding, sondern nach außen eine Schalterstellung und intern ein System von Regelkreisen, gewissermaßen ein Zustand. Man sagt jedenfalls: 'Er fliegt auf Autopilot' und nicht etwa: 'Er fliegt auf dem Autopiloten'. Ich jedenfalls finde beide OK..